# RecurrenceInterval on Windows Phone 7 - Enumeration Hourly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

So, I'm planning on creating a reminder app for WP7 using the Microsoft.Phone.Scheduler class, and I want to set up the Recurrence Interval of the reminder notification.
The problem is: The available interval is only Daily, Weekly, Monthly or Yearly.
I was wondering if there's anyway to set up a Hourly Recurrence Interval.

The user will set up a initial time end and end time, and I wanted to have hourly notifications on this period of time. Is that possible. I was thinking of something like this:

```
while (beginTime < endTime)
{
beginTime += 01:00:00;
}
```

But that's not right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's anyway to set up a Hourly Recurrence Interval.

There isn't.

Comment: But isn't there a way to workaround on this? For example, add a counter for each notification, add another hour; or something similar?

Comment: Not really, no. The closest you get is a live tile update (default 30 minutes, but can be set to 1 hour as well), pushing toast notifications. You can't use the Reminder/Alert class with a 1 hour recurrence interval.

Comment: That's good enought. Haven't thought about this possibilities. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could Schedule 24 daily alarms in order to have a hourly reminder, or e.g. 4 daily alarms if you want to be reminded every 8 hours. 
The drawback in this workaround is that you can schedule max 50 alarms per application, and it is not enough in most of the cases.